# Unable to allocate 660. GiB eventhough I have 7961miB space

Tags: one-hot-encoding, ubuntu-22.04, imdb

I am trying to run 1-hot encoding on IMDB data which I loaded from keras.datasets. But When I run `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_seq)` in the following context, I am getting MemoryError as attatched image, eventhough I have 7961mib space on my RTX 4060 TI (when I checked `nvidia-smi` after failure). I am using venv virtual environment on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and using tensorflow=2.13 and my computer has 32gbx2 RAM. I want to 1-hot encode `train_seq` into (20000, 100, 500) ndarray. Thanks in advance.

#### MemoryError

[image: MemoryError]

#### `nvidia smi` after failure

[image: nvidia smi after failure]

#### Full code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.imdb.load_data()
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
train_seq = pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=100)
valid_seq = pad_sequences(x_valid, maxlen=100)
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_seq)
```

I've tried `sudo kill -9 <PID>` and restarted my python kernel and ran again. And ran the same code on my google colab with T4 runtime. (T4 worked well and it only used GPU RAM
4.6 / 15.0 GB when I've checked after running.)